# Check function signature in Typecript

Tags: typescript, function

I overloaded a function in order to create buttons with a specific callback `action` when they will be clicked.

1. I want to force the call of `createButton()` with an `action` with **no parameters** if I need to create a `Button1`
2. I want to force the call with an `action` with a `MyParam` parameter to create a `Button2`.

I could cast `Button1` into `Button2` passing a parameter `action` such as `() => void` like so :

```
const btn: Button2 = createButton({ label: "x", action: (/* no params here */) => void 0 }); // returns a Button1
```

so I added the `hasActionParam` property to really identify the type of the buttons and achieve rule **2.**

**But I now need to fill `hasActionParam` in the implementation and I do not know how to proceed. I need to check if the signature of the `action` property has a parameter `MyParam` or not. Can someone help me doing so ?**

```
interface Button1 {
  label: string;
  action: () => void;
  hasActionParam: false;
}
interface Button2 {
  label: string;
  action: (param: MyParam) => void;
  hasActionParam: true;
}

function createButton({ label, action }: { label: string; action: () => void }): Button1;
function createButton({ label, action }: { label: string; action: (param: MyParam) => void }): Button2;
function createButton({
  label = "",
  action
}: { label: string; action: () => void | (param: MyParam) => void }): Button1 | Button2 {
  return {
    label,
    action,
    hasActionParam: /* need some help */ ? true : false
  };
}
```

Comment: I don't really get why this is necessary... Why not just pass `MyParam` to the button's `action` method regardless if it takes one or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function has a `length` property that returns the number of arguments the function accepts.

```js
const a = () => null
console.log(a.length) // 0

const b = (arg) => null
console.log(b.length) // 1
```

Which means you can check if the action function has a `param` parameter like so:

```
export function createButton({
  label = "",
  action
}: ButtonParam & { label: string; action: () => void | (param: MyParam) => void }): Button1 | Button2 {
  return {
    label,
    action,
    hasActionParam: action.length > 0
  };
}
```

Comment: By curiosity, do you know if there is another way than checking args to check that the function action is like () => void or (param: MyParam) => void ? Because it seems that functions signatures cannot be considered as type

Comment: "that functions signatures cannot be considered as type" That's not true. The type `Parameters<(arg: string) => null>` is equivalent to the type `[arg: string]`.

Comment: Wow it's interesting ! However, even knowing that I don't see the way I could check that the `action` function is of "type" `() => void` or `(param: MyParam) => void`. Because in the case there would be a third option, then `action.length > 0` won't be enough

Answer (score 0):

I finally achieve my purpose with

```
interface Button<HasParam extends boolean> {
  label: string;
  action: HasParam extends true ? (param: MyParam) => void : () => void;
}

function createButton<HasParam extends false>({ label, action }: { label: string; action: () => void }): Button<HasParam>;
function createButton<HasParam extends true>({ label, action }: { label: string; action: (param: MyParam) => void }): Button<HasParam>;
function createButton<HasParam extends boolean>({
  label = "",
  action
}: { label: string; action: () => void | (param: MyParam) => void }): Button<HasParam> {
  return {
    label,
    action,
  };
}
```

```
const btn1: Button<false> = createButton<false>({ label: "x", action: () => void 0 }); //✅ 
const btn2: Button<false> = createButton<false>({ label: "x", action: (param: MyParam) => void 0 }); //❌ 
const btn3: Button<true> = createButton<true>({ label: "x", action: (param: MyParam) => void 0 }); //✅ 
const btn4: Button<true> = createButton<true>({ label: "x", action: () => void 0 }); //❌
```